WSL Ubuntu: How to setup gcc to cross-compile for arm with a specific glibc version?
I'm not really an expert of linux, so i'm feeling a bit lost.
I'm running an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS image in WSL, as i need to cross-compile a program for an ARM linux pc (a BeagleBone Black, "BBB" from now) using a Windows PC. That image was automagically installed by the Powershell command WSL.exe --install and i'm fine with it.
I've been able to add the armhf architecture, the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and to build my program but i've got a glibc version error from the BBB.
So i tried to install the same GCC version that's on the BBB, which is the 10, but no luck. Tried the 9 and same result.

This is how i have installed everything on the WSL UBUNTU (omitting all the update/upgrade):
    sudo bash -c "echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports       jammy main restricted universe multiverse'            >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list"
    sudo bash -c "echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports       jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse'    >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list"
    sudo bash -c "echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports       jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse'   >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list"
    sudo bash -c "echo 'deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports       jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse'  >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/armhf.list"
    sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
    sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall -y
    sudo apt install  gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf -y
    sudo update-alternatives --install \
                          /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc          arm-gcc          /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-9 \
                100 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cc           arm-cc           /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-c++          arm-c++          /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp          arm-cpp          /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-cpp-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++          arm-g++          /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov         arm-gcov         /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-dump    arm-gcov-dump    /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-dump-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-tool    arm-gcov-tool    /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcov-tool-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-lto-dump     arm-lto-dump     /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-lto-dump-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar       arm-gcc-ar       /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ar-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm       arm-gcc-nm       /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-nm-9 \
                --slave   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib   arm-gcc-ranlib   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-ranlib-9
    sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev:armhf -y

Now, instead of building my project, which takes too much time, I've built the sample code in the accepted answer of this question both on the UBUNTU and the BBB.
The one built on the BBB outputs:
GNU libc version: 2.31
The one build on the PC always output this error:
./glibc-version-ARM: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./glibc-version-ARM)
So, i am clearly missing something which is not related to the GCC version. Could someone help me making my cross-compiling working?

Did you install libc6-arm64-cross,  libc6-armel-cross, or libc6-armhf-armhf-cross or whatever libc-yourplatform.... package?

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly: all the steps i've done are listed in the question. Monday i'll try to install the libc6-armhf-armhf-cross and see what happens. Question: How do i know that it is the version i need?

Beaglebone Black has ARM Cortex A8 cores (implements  ARMv7-A architecture). So if you installed the libc6-armhf-armhf-cross and gcc-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf, you are done. You must compile your code with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.

Additionally, you can download cross toolchains from Linaro and ARM.

Even you can find native windows builds, Visual Studio Code extension, Docerfile for linaro, and this and this docker images from dockerhub.

But you must research more. I haven't your board. But I did so many times for other boards and it is not a hard task.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly: installing libc6-armhf-cross returns libc6-armhf-cross is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu1cross3). So it was automatically installed by some of the command i've run before. There's a way to install an older version?

A fully up-to-date Ubuntu 22.04 installation should have glibc 2.35 installed [1], while your BeagleBone has glibc 2.31. glibc is NOT forward-compatible, which means programs you build for glibc 2.35 are not guaranteed to run on earlier versions of glibc.
The solution is to either update the software on your board to a newer version, if possible (one that comes with glibc 2.35+), or to compile using an older version of glibc -- the simplest way IMO would be to install Ubuntu 20.04, which uses glibc 2.31.
libgcc should be forward-compatible, so the GCC version shouldn't matter.
